# How can I insert a substring(a,b) in a 2d array in Java? (each character in a position of the array)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, substring

I'm trying to make an alphabet soup but I keep getting the "String index out of range" error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)

when I try to insert the substring dynamically. I want to generate dynamic indexes for the substring() so that after each iteration of the nested loop it increases it's indexes by one and the next letter of the word is inserted in the next position of the array.
(The fRandom is meant to insert each word in a random row of the array).

Here's my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        
        int i; int j; int fRandom;
        int counter = 0; String word = "";
        int x = 0; int y = 0;
        
        String matrix[][] = new String[20][20];
        
        for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            fRandom = random.nextInt(19);
            for(j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                if(counter < 5){
                    System.out.println("Enter word between 3 and 5 characters");
                    word = read.next();
                    while(word.length() > 5 || word.length() < 3){
                    System.out.println("Must have between 3 and 5 characters");
                    word = read.next();
                }
                }
                matrix[fRandom][j] = word.substring(x++, y++);
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
```

Whenever I run the program with a static substring(0,1) it doesn't throw any errors but the same letter is inserted into every position of the array, and if I use the substring(0) with only the start index, the entire word goes into each position of the array.
I have tried printing at different stages of the code to see what is wrong, and I've narrowed it to the substring() method, everything else works fine.
I've also tried changing the fRandom to "fRandom = random.nextInt(20)" but it throws an error.
Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I think you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you *actually* trying to do? Side note: `random.nextInt(19)` never returns `19` - I don't know what you're trying to do, but my guess is you want `random.nextInt(20)`

Comment: If you want to become a software developer, you will need debugging skills. As a professional, you won't be able to come to Stack Overflow every time. It so happens, this is a good program to practice debugging.  Here are three things commonly used in debugging:  1) Pretend you are the computer. Follow the flow of the program. If needed, used pen and paper for the computer memory. 2) Insert `System.out.println (...);` lines into the code.  In place of "...", put something to indicate where the program is, and the values of variables. 3) Use a debugger, often built into an IDE.

Comment: What is the significance of the variables x & y. Every time you enter a word they both increment by 1 - x++, y++. They very quickly get greater than the length of the string entered and generate the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Off-topic, because it doesn't cause the out-of-bounds condtion: It is useful to consult the API of classes, interfaces, and methods you use.  What do you want to do with `word.substring(x++, y++);` ? What do you think the  does? Try a debugging test with this code: `String foo = "Hello, World!";         System.out.println ("Foo 7 >" +foo.substring (7,7)  + "< ");` . If you wonder about that result,  see the [`.subString (int, int)` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))

Comment: Can you, please, edit the question again, to include the complete stack trace? The stack trace will indicate which line of your code triggered the error. Also, show samples of input and the result of each.